.Net MAUI handling keyboard input
I 'am creating a Windows .Net MAUI app the when a key is pressed on the keyboard it creates a sound that you have uploaded. Is there anything in .Net MAUI that can verify that the key is pressed on the keyboard? The app doesn't have any entry as it should work just by uploading the file and pressing any key on the keyboard. I wish not to make a keylogger just want to somehow verify that any key is pressed.
Example: you press any key on the keyboard and you hear the M1 Garand ping sound.
repo for code: https://github.com/MaleB-08/KeyCap_Sounds
I have tried some code that I found on StackOverflow but no concreate answer on it and I have looked on Microsoft documentation but no success.

I wish for the app to run in the background and just for keystrokes (example you press any key on the keyboard it makes the M1 Garand ping sound). I wish to not log any key that is pressed like a keylogger just the motion of the key being pressed.

What do you mean the motion of the key being pressed? If you want to handle keyboard input, you can refer to Plugin.Maui.KeyListener.

Thank you very much this is what I have been looking for as it provides me with the keyboard input I need.

No worries, I've converted into an answer as it may help others facing the same needs under the circumstances.


I wish not to make a keylogger just want to somehow verify that any
key is pressed. Example: you press any key on the keyboard and you
hear the M1 Garand ping sound.

You can use Plugin.Maui.KeyListener which can provide KeyboardBehavior to listen for keyboard up (pressed) and down (released) events on any view in a .NET MAUI application. This is useful in situations where a KeyboardAccelerator isn't suitable.
